# Macros de pre compilacao em C

Tags: c, compilação, diretivas-de-compilação

Fiz a seguinte função para um trabalho da faculdade que cria um menu de opções genérico de forma a agilizar o desenvolvimento do trabalho, ela é baseada no funcionamento do printf que recebe argumentos variáveis através da stdarg.h, mas todavia ainda falta melhorias, percebi a função printf consegui avisar erros de sintaxe em tempo de programação, por exemplo se faltar argumentos nela, pesquisei um pouco e parece que para fazer essa verificação é usado diretivas de processamento "posso estar completamente errado, não tenho certeza". Mas enfim, o que eu preciso usar para que possa ser verificado a sintaxe da quantidade de argumentos passados para a função imprimir?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void menuGraphics(int quantidadeArgumentos, char *frasePrincipal , ...){
    system("clear");
    char *string;
    va_list parametros;
    
    va_start(parametros, quantidadeArgumentos);
    
    printf("\n%50s ___________________________________________________________\n"
            "%50s|               %-35s         |\n"
            "%50s|                                                           |\n", "\0", "\0", frasePrincipal, "\0");
    for(int i = 0; i<quantidadeArgumentos; i++){
        
        string = va_arg(parametros, char *);
        
        printf("%50s|   %2d- %-25s                           |\n","\0", i+1, string);
        
    }
    printf("%50s|___________________________________________________________|\n", "\0");
    va_end(parametros);
    
}

int main(){
    menuGraphics(4, "teste", "teste 1", "teste 2", "teste 3", "teste 4");//funcao passada com a quantidade de argumentos certa
    
    Sleep(2000);
    menuGraphics(4, "teste", "teste 1", "teste 2", "teste 3"); // funcao passada com a quantidade errada
    
    
}
```

Comment: O *pré-processador* é executado um passo antes da compilação, suas instruções chamam-se diretivas, ocupam uma linha e são iniciadas com o caractere `#`. O *pré-processador* lê os arquivos fonte e realizando conversões léxicas os entrega em um único arquivo. As diretivas de pré-processamento controlam o comportamento do pré-processador e exibem os seguintes recursos: compilação condicional, substituição de texto(macro), inclusão de arquivos e geração de alertas. Você não estaria confundindo com *lint* uma ferramenta de análise de código usada para sinalizar em tempo real erros e bugs no código

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza do que tenho que usar, por isso que comentei que talvez esteja completamente errado.